# splitting jars into multiple dex files

Tags: android, android-build, dex

I am working with the **Apache POI** jars and since they have more than 65000 methods, they do not compile and I get the error:

> trouble writing output: Too many methods: 65561; max is 65536. By
>   package:...

I followed [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) tutorial, but I didn't understand how exactly it would work on the jars and split them as I still get the same error when I run `build.xml`

Could someone please tell me how I can split the jars into multiple dex files?

Answer (score 0):

For POI only it could be enough to include the line 
dex.force.jumbo=true
in project.properties.

It worked for me until I added Drive SDK.

Comment: doesn't work for me :(
I still get the 'Too many methods...' error